# truck starts when cold, need a jump to start after that

Tags: electrical

truck starts when cold, need a jump to start after that, voltage at battery drops to 4or 6 when starting, then stablizes at 11.5 or 11.7, We've already put in a new starter thinking that was the prolem. It worked well for a couple days, now back to how it acted before.

Comment: So Lada Riva or Tata special? If you give us the make model, year, miles and engine that may possibly help guess what is happening...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd agree with Solar Mike here, we need vehicle information to help ... I'd suspect the battery is at fault, though.

Comment: If the voltage across the battery is only 11.5-11.7 with the vehicle running, I'd sooner suspect the alternator.  The battery may have been destroyed by a bad alternator as well.  @SolarMike I don't think it's a RIva, or even a Lada.  AvtoVAZ didn't make trucks.  It's more likely an UAZ or an AMO ZiL . . . </jokeflag>